# openURL with NSUserDefaults Key from Settings.bundle

Tags: ios, settings, key, nsuserdefaults, settings.bundle

im trying to open the url i saved in the iphone settings (**Settings.bundle**) plist and it saves, but now I'm trying to open the url in safari with the url i saved in the **key**

I have researched and found nothing, thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize this at first, but none of the values saved in the settings.bundle plist are active until the user actually opens the settings for the first time. So if you want to save some URL there or setting, you need to have a default value to fall back on if they haven't opened up the settings.